# Set tag on Azure APIM API from CLI

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, azure-api-management, apim

I am searching for a CLI way to set tags on an azure apim api instance.  I am talking about an API tag, which seems to be different from tags on that api-service or other api resources.  This means that (to my knowledge)
`Get-AzTag -ResourceId`
doesn't work for api's (I have done it with the id of the api and the list is empty, while the portal shows tags).  Having to do this for 300+ interfaces using the azure portal is a bit cumbersome .

[image: What I mean in the azure portal]

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways where azure cli offers to applying tags :

.[az tag create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/tag#az_tag_create)

.[az tag update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/tag#az_tag_update)

Below is an example for create a tag :

```
 az tag create --resource-id  $resource  --tags Dept=Finance Status=Normal
```

To get list of tags you can use below example code:

```
 az tag list --resource-id
```

For further details Please refer this link:-
. [Using azure cli Apply tags.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-resources?tabs=json#azure-cli) .

Secondary ,we can [add /set tags using Powershell as well to our api of APIM](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/21817).

Comment: Hello, your solution can set a tag on APIM instance but (to my knowledge) not on an API inside the APIM itself.  These kinds of tags are not of the (name,value)-pair kind.

Comment: Could you please refer this [Git-hub Issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/21817).

Comment: Hello, from the git issue it seems that you are right.  Unfortunately (and this has nothing to with your suggestions) I have not been able to get this to work.  It is not clear what I need to do in powershell and there seem to be two competing but incompatible versions of the toolings.  I'll ask our operations guys to hav e ago at it.  They are more experienced in PowerShell.  Tx already for the suggestions.  I'll upvote it once I can confirm (from experience) that it works.